# overriding istream and ofstream

Tags: c++, overriding, fstream

Im having trouble overriding the `<<` and `>>` operators for the file stream.

```
struct Reading
{
    int hour;
    double temp;

    Reading()
        : hour{ 0 }, temp{ 0 } {};
    Reading(int h, double t)
        : hour{ h }, temp{ t } {};
};

ifstream& operator<<(ifstream& ifs, const Reading& reading)
{
    return ifs << '(' << reading.hour << ',' << reading.temp << ')' << endl;
}

ofstream& operator>>(ofstream& ofs, Reading& reading)
{
    ofs >> reading.hour;
    ofs >> reading.temp;
    return ofs;
}
```

I don't have a problem when i try to override the iostream in the same manner, its just with the file stream. Could you indicated what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Please elaborate on what's going wrong.

Comment: well, if i want to override `iostream` such as `istream& operator>> (// some code)` it works, but when i try to override the `ifstream`, i get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have confused `ifstream` (short for *in*-filestream) which is for input and `ofstream` (short for *out*-filestream) which is for output.